# JavaScript Print Failing with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'll start by noting that I have the main module with a dropdown which dynamically populates `<div id='printableArea'></div>`. Within this div, the dynamic content will provide (1) a print button: `<input id='printButton' type='button' value='Print'>` and (2) jQuery to output the content onto a blank page for printing:

```
$('#printButton').on('click',function(){
    printData();
});

function printData() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printableArea");
    newWin = window.open("","_blank");
    newWin.document.write('<html><head><title></title><style type="text/css">@page {  size: portrait; -webkit-print-color-adjust:economy;}' + '</style></head><body>');
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.document.write('</body></html>');

    setTimeout(function(){
        newWin.print();
    }, 1000);

    return false;
}
```

It appears to work but not all the time. Once the print button is clicked, the new window appears with the dynamic content as intended but the printing dialog does not display (within Chrome). If I switch back to the main page with the dropdown then switch back to the new window, the print dialog is displayed. I guess the setTimeout is triggered once the main page recieves focus again... and I made that assumption because I notice the print button is still in focus as if I was clicking and holding it.

I've been trying to tackle this problem for hours and I've given up. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try injecting that script on the popup page.  Like maybe `newWin.document.write('<script>print();</script></body></html>');`

Comment: Great minds think alike but that didn't work. For some reason, it does not execute the contents within <script></script>. In fact, it crashes the whole AJAX element that populates #printableArea.

Comment: Try closing the document before printing: `newWin.document.close();`.

Comment: @Xufox No good. The issue still resides and switching back to the main page then back to the new window triggers the printing rather than printing as soon as the new page is launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround/solution... which was attempted before but failed due to poor syntax (not escaping correctly as I'm using PHP).

```
newWin.document.write('\\x3Cscript>');   // Escaped <script>
newWin.document.write('print();');
newWin.document.write('\\x3C/script>');  // Escaped </script>
```

-- Thanks to Taplar for bringing up that approach again.